# Opening error popover from service in Angular 2

Tags: angularjs, angular, ng-bootstrap

I would like to create a service which will be responsible for opening bootstrap popovers with errors and success communicates. I have two components ErrorComponent, SuccessComponent and one service called CommunicatesComponent. I would like to use this service to open popover like

```
service.error('some error')
service.success('success!')
```

And this should display popover with provided text as argument. What I am doing is setting component property in service like followed and use this property in this service:

ErrorComponent

```
export class ErrorComponent implements OnInit {
    public text:string;
    @ViewChild('errorPopover') private errorPopover: NgbPopover;

    constructor(private communicatesService:CommunicatesService) {       
    }

    public ngOnInit() {
        this.communicatesService.setErrorComponent(this)
    }
}
```

Service:

```
@Injectable()
export class CommunicatesService {
    private errorComponent:ErrorComponent

    public setErrorComponent(component:ErrorComponent) {
        this.errorComponent = component;
    }

    public error(text:string) {
        console.log(this.errorComponent)
       // this.errorComponent.text = text;
    }
}
```

Unfortunitelly, it seems that my component object is not provided well, because console log prints undefined. How it should be done?

Regards

Answer (score 1):

There are two things I would change in your design

1. ErrorComponent and CommunicatesService depends on each other. It's good to avoid it - CommunicatesService could easily work with different components. So you could create an rx Observable public property of the service, so any component can subscribe to it. When `service.success('success!')`, the service will send the message text to the subscribers.
2. In ErrorComponent, you get the popover component as a `@ViewChild`. You could consider binding `ErrorComponent.text` to the popover directly (reversing the dependency).

These changes could solve the problems you have and make the design looser - easier to understand and maintain.

Comment: How to implement solution 1?

Comment: For creating an Observable object, use Rx.Subject: https://github.com/Reactive-Extensions/RxJS/blob/master/doc/api/subjects/subject.md It allows you to easily push messages into it. You just call `subject.onNext(message);` and subscribers get notified.

Comment: I have installed rxjs and imported but I receive 'cannot find name Rx' in code: private errorObservable = new Rx.Subject();

Comment: RxJS is already included in Angular, so it was not necessary to install it. To import Rx.Subject, `import {Subject} from 'rxjs/Subject';`. Then you can address it without the Rx prefix - just as `new Subject()`.

Comment: I have added a new post above, please check